# Tracking even with AsNoTracking()

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a read only query that is set with `AsNoTracking()`, but the query is still tracking.  Example:

```
// Grab office with id (do not include address)
var offfice = _context.Office
    .AsNoTracking()
    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id)
```

```
// Grab the first office with address id, or give me the first one
var address = _context.Address
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(e => e.Office)
    .Where(e => id == null || e.Office.Any(o => o.AddressId == id))
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

Taking the single item from the query above and then doing the following:

```
address.Address1 = "New Address";

_context.Address.Update(address);

office.Name = "New Office Name";

_context.Office.Update(office);  // Throws tracking error here, on Office Id

_context.SaveChanges();
```

If I have set both queries to AsNoTracking() and and forcing updates of objects myself, why am I getting a tracking error on something that shouldn't be tracking?

Thanks.

Comment: tracking started at `_context.Address.Update(address)`; this command update using id of an instance of address  and start tracking

Comment: when querying for address, you are also including the office, then when you start tracking the address (with the first `.Update`) it also starts tracking the navigation prop (`address.Office`). Then you `.Update` the office, but it already exists, because EF sees an entity with the same id.

Comment: Okay, so what is the point of `AsNoTracking` then?  I don't want anything to be tracked, including any `Include` I add.